# JSON Schema - dropdown based on selected value other dropdown

Tags: json, dropdown, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Lets say i've the following data structure

```
Option A
Option B
    Option B1
        Option B2.1
        Option B2.2
```

I am trying to create an enums stucture that allows this so I can generate a dropdown based on the value of the previous selected dropdown.

Examples :

```
Select option A -> No additional dropdowns
Select option B -> Generate dropdown with Option B1
Select option B1 -> Generate dropdown with Option B2.1 and Option B2.2
```

This would work when you want to create an array with childeren is there anything similar possible for enums

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",

  "definitions": {
    "medicine": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "value": { "type": "string" },
        "categories": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/medicine" }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "person": { "$ref": "#/definitions/medicine" }
  }
```

}

And then the enum structure to be something like this

```
[
     { 
        "value ":  "Option A" 
     }, 
     { 
        "value ":  "Option B ", 
        "categories ": [ 
         { 
            "value ":  "Option B1 ", 
            "categories ": [ 
             {
                "value ":  "Option B1.1" 
             }, 
             { 
                "value ":  "Option B1.2" 
             } 
           ] 
         } 
       ] 
    }
]
```

So I am looking for a data structure that would allow me to make dropdowns based on the values selected here in a own layout generation engine.

Comment: JSON Schema was not designed for form generation. In other words, there is no standard for generating a form from a JSON Schema. Every implementation does it their own way. So, whatever answer there might be to this question, it will necessarily be implementation specific. That said, I'm not aware of any implementation that supports form generation of this complexity.

Comment: What is exactly that you look for? Are you asking about JSON schema that reflects described dependencies?

Answer (score 6):

Have you considered flattening your structure so that it's easier to look up options and sub-options?

Let's imagine that you've got an initial array for the root options:

```js
[
  'opt_a',
  'opt_b'
]
```

Then you have a flattened map of all options from which you can derive labels and subsequent dropdowns:

```js
{
  opt_a: {
    label: 'Option A'
  },
  opt_b: {
    label: 'Option B',
    children: ['opt_b1']
  },
  opt_b1: {
    label: 'Option B1',
    children: ['opt_b11', 'opt_b12']
  }
  opt_b11: {
    label: 'Option B1.1'
  }
  opt_b12: {
    label: 'Option B1.2'
  }
}
```

I hope this answers your question and is self-explanatory enough.